# how to insert a date in sqlite from java?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, javafx-2

I'm trying to insert a date in SQLite database, can anyone help me with the query 
this is my query:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "INSERT INTO date VALUES (10/10/2020)");
```

an this is the error that i'm having :

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing
>   database (near "30": syntax error)

Comment: The format you have to use is : `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: query does not return ResultSet     thats what i had when i used      ResultSet rsNote = stmtNote.executeQuery( "INSERT INTO date VALUES (2020-10-10)");

Comment: You shouldn't use `executeQuery` for insert operation. Use `executeUpdate` or `execute`. http://javaconceptoftheday.com/difference-between-executequery-executeupdate-execute-in-jdbc/

Comment: stmtNote.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO date VALUES (2020-10-10)");            and it added 2000 to the database

Comment: Don't get me wrong...but are you really doing any research before asking? You post the error and wait for answer!!!

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: @ShaishavJogani No, for date-time values use date-time objects, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

"INSERT INTO date VALUES (2020-10-10)" will insert 2000, as you reported, because 2020-10-10 = 2010-10 = 2000 (this is an integer evaluation).  If you want a string, then specify it - "INSERT INTO date VALUES ('2020-10-10')"